# How to center a bootstrap well?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image][image]
I can't seem to get this well to align with the center of the page. It seems like it should be easy but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please post your code. Let us see what you have done untill now. Only then we could help you better

Comment: CSS not needed, just post your html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**offset classes**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) provided by Bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="well">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/KzdGZr)**

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap is based on a grid system of 12 columns.  If you want the above message submission box centered I would place it in a column space of ~6 and have ~3 columns on each side of it like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">[Empty DIV]</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">[Summision Box]</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">[Empty DIV]</div>
</div>
```